# iphone 5 Default-568h@2x.png image works on simulator, but not on actual device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

So,

I am trying to add iPhone 5 support to one of my apps.  I've added the splash screen for the 4" version, and the file is named: Default-568h@2x.png.

When running in the iOS Simulator on the 4" mode, everything functions correctly.

However, when I run the same app on my iPhone 5 device, it still loads the old @2x image in black letter box.

I've tried deleting and re-adding the image.  I've tried cleaning the build and re-building. I've tried deleting the app and re-running.

I've started new projects in XCode, using the 568 image, and they work fine on my device.  But, this is an old project that I am trying to convert.

Has anyone ran into something like this?  I'm guessing its some setting somewhere, I jsut cannot find it for the life of me.

Please help!

Comment: Opened the package contents of the built app.  And, Default-568h@2x.png isn't in there.  So, for some reason it adds it to the simulator package, but not the device package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be the wrong format PNG.  Photoshop wouldn't open the file. Only thing I could think of is my designer renamed a .jpg to .png....

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the image has been added to the target. If you select your image file in the Project Navigator (left pane) the Utilities pane (right pane) should have a checkmark under 'Target Membership' next to your target. 
Alternatively, with the project selected, select your target then the Summary tab. Drag your image into the correct spot in the 'Launch Images' section.